# Python bs4 - find_all multiple tags and classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing some scraping and ran into an issue.

Right now my code looks like:

```
pn = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "full"})
pfp = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "fp active"})
```

In the above example I am iterating over the page twice. Is it possible to do a find_all on both tags/classes so I can ensure I am scraping data accurately?

Thank you

Comment: What does the `bs4` documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `BS4 4.7.1` or above you can use `css` selector.

```
soup.select('a.full,td.fp.active')
```

OR

```
soup.select('.full,.fp.active')
```

Comment: This works and the results are the same as my answer. Not sure which answer is "better" though.

Comment: @D3l_Gato : CSS selector are much faster in compare to find_all().I would always suggest CSS selector to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in a list, Beautiful Soup will allow a string match against any item in that list:

```py
soup.find_all(["a", "td"], {"class": ["full", "fp active"]})
```

Docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list

Comment: While it probably works, an edge case you may want to check is that this might match not just a `a.full` but also `a.fp`.  (Not totally sure of that, but seems possible.)

Comment: Thanks for your edit and comment Brad. My initial testing appears to be OK but I am not sure my source doc has a 'fp' tag. I will test. Thanks so much.